# Combining files of multiple directories as Hadoop input

Tags: hadoop

There are two folders *A* and *B* with *n* documents each. I want to process each combination of file pairs in *A* and *B*, i.e. (A<sub>0</sub>, B<sub>0</sub>), (A<sub>0</sub>, B<sub>1</sub>), ... , (A<sub>1</sub>, B<sub>0</sub>), (A<sub>1</sub>, B<sub>1</sub>), ... (A<sub>n</sub>, B<sub>0</sub>), ... , (A<sub>n</sub>, B<sub>n</sub>).

Is there a chance to write an derived (File)InputFormat for that job? Or would it be better to share one document collection as side data (using a static list) and process only the other collection as input data?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that what you are trying to achieve is a cross join. Hive, as of version 0.10 already supports cross joins so you may want to use it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. As we had not yet build up the Hive infrastructure on our cluster, I solved the problem by creating a combination file beforehand, parse it as Hadoop input and open the files in the mapping. Probably not very subtle, but it works...